# What Method of Shared Code Files Does Visual Studio/ReSharper Perform Better With?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance, resharper, shared-project

### Setup

> VS Enterprise 15.7.6
>   ReSharper Ultimate 2018.1.3

I have to deploy .net Class Libraries without any expediencies on other dlls outside of the .net Framework and I'm trying to figure out Visual Studio / ReSharper performance implications (the performance of the IDE itself, not the compiled/deployed code) for sharing code files.

My solution has 23 .net 4.5.2 class library projects, and 1 [shared project](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/shared-project-an-impressive-features-of-visual-studio-201/).  This shared project is unique to this client.  I also have shared code that is not unique to the client that is shared as a [source only nuget package](https://nikcodes.com/2013/10/23/packaging-source-code-with-nuget/).  This means the same code is added to every project and checked into TFS under every project.

### Question

Would Visual Studio / ReSharper have better performance if I removed all the source only NuGet files, and added all of these files to the [Shared Project](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/shared-project-an-impressive-features-of-visual-studio-201/)?

Currently VS spends a lot of CPUs each time I type a keystroke, and I'm wondering if this change would help.  Only Negative is that any upgrade of the Source Only Nuget Package would be manual...

### Update 1 Added PrefView

[image]

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio/Resharper? Both techniques are pretty deprecated if you'd ask me and I haven't encountered them in a long time. Shared Projects were mostly introduced to support multi-platform builds that share sources. With the introdution of NetStandard and .NET Core, this problem should now be largely reduced.

Consider using PerfView to figure out what VisualStudio /  Resharper is spending it's time on. https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview

Comment: @jessehouwing I work in MS Dynamics, which is not converting to .Net Core anytime soon, and even if it did, this wouldn't resolve the issues that I'm having to overcome.  I've added the versions, but I'm hoping for an answer that would be version agnostic.

Comment: When you run a perfview, can you see what is taking the most cpu cycles?

Comment: @jessehouwing I've added my prefview image.  Looks like ntdll is using up the most...

Comment: Doubleclick the high-users to dig into the stacktrace

Comment: Looks like Visual Studio is at 12.5%, if you have a quad-core CPU with hyperthreading, that means that one core is at 100%.

Comment: I may not be reading this right, but I think these are all threads within the devenv process, so I'm not sure what else to do.  Double clicking just opens the Callers tab, and that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: The callers tab will show you hopefully a useful methodname that may suggest which feature, extension, plugin is actually causing the calls.

Comment: Only method name I see is ntdll!_RTLUserThreadStart

Comment: My suggestion is to open a ticket on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html and to provide the perfview trace.